# Extjs4 panel is rendered before containing image is loaded

Tags: javascript, extjs

I got an custom container which has two "xtype:image" components. I found that the first time the panel is rendered, it's done before the image is fully loaded, i.e. it's rendered without the images.

After the initial rendering, anything that will trigger rerendering will fix the problem, like F5 or even F12 to open the dev tools.

My guess is that the when rendering happens, the images are not fully loaded yet.

Is there a way to have the panel's rendering happen after the images are fully loaded?

Comment: You can use the image's load event

Comment: Should I post it as an answer?

Comment: Diego, you should have posted it as an answer and not a comment.